# watch framework with healthkit capabilities

Tags: frameworks, watchos

Is possible to create dynamic watch framework with healthkit capabilities?

I have created a watch framework *(File > New Target > Target > [WatchOS]  Watch Framework )* that is suppose to do all the healthkit work iincluding starting a workout to get current user heart rate data.
I am aware that framework menu does not have "Capabilities" Tab like the Targets but nonetheless I have enable the main target to HealthKit (with entitlements). The HealthKit framework and entitlements to have the newly created framework as a selected option but i still get the below error, any suggestions?

**"Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement."**